# Swift 3 Dispatch Queue conversion

Tags: swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I am new to Swift and am having difficulty converting all of my code to the Swift 3. Specifically, my problem is with the Dispatch Queue. Here is my code:

```
dispatch_group_notify(workGroup, DispatchQueue.main){
    self.descs = [self.query1desc, self.query2desc]
    self.carouselView.reloadData()
}
```

Does anyone know what changes I need to make to have it compatible with Swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
workGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    self.descs = [self.query1desc, self.query2desc]
    self.carouselView.reloadData()
})
```